# XMLType: group by select query

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle12c

I have this XML-based query in Oracle 12c:

```
  SELECT XMLELEMENT (
            "companiesArray",
            XMLAGG (
               XMLELEMENT (
                  "CompanyElement",
                  XMLFOREST (d.poclcdde AS "companyCode"),
                  (SELECT XMLELEMENT (
                             "policiesArray",
                             XMLAGG (
                                XMLELEMENT (
                                   "PolicyElement",
                                   XMLELEMENT ("policyNumber", de.polinpol),
                                   XMLELEMENT ("companyCode", de.policdde),
                                   XMLELEMENT ("productCode", de.politipo))))
                     FROM dtpoli de
                    WHERE de.polinpol = d.poclnpol AND de.policdde = d.poclcdde))))
    FROM dtpocl d
   WHERE d.poclcdcl = 202126
```

I get this result:

```
<companiesArray>
    <CompanyElement>
        <companyCode>100</companyCode>
        <policiesArray>
            <PolicyElement>
                <policyNumber>1000005</policyNumber>
                <companyCode>100</companyCode>
                <productCode>02</productCode>
            </PolicyElement>
        </policiesArray>
    </CompanyElement>
    <CompanyElement>
        <companyCode>100</companyCode>
        <policiesArray>
            <PolicyElement>
                <policyNumber>9902658</policyNumber>
                <companyCode>100</companyCode>
                <productCode>02</productCode>
            </PolicyElement>
        </policiesArray>
    </CompanyElement>
    <CompanyElement>
        <companyCode>200</companyCode>
        <policiesArray>
            <PolicyElement>
                <policyNumber>1000005</policyNumber>
                <companyCode>200</companyCode>
                <productCode>02</productCode>
            </PolicyElement>
        </policiesArray>
    </CompanyElement>
</companiesArray>
```

But I want to group the result by companyCode (d.poclcdde). As this:

```
<companiesArray>
    <CompanyElement>
        <companyCode>100</companyCode>
        <policiesArray>
            <PolicyElement>
                <policyNumber>1000005</policyNumber>
                <companyCode>100</companyCode>
                <productCode>02</productCode>
            </PolicyElement>
            <PolicyElement>
                <policyNumber>9902658</policyNumber>
                <companyCode>100</companyCode>
                <productCode>02</productCode>
            </PolicyElement>
        </policiesArray>
    </CompanyElement>
    <CompanyElement>
        <companyCode>200</companyCode>
        <policiesArray>
            <PolicyElement>
                <policyNumber>1000005</policyNumber>
                <companyCode>200</companyCode>
                <productCode>02</productCode>
            </PolicyElement>
        </policiesArray>
    </CompanyElement>
</companiesArray>
```

I've tried some approaches but with no success. If I put a `GROUP BY d.poclcdde` I get two different records with the same XML structure, but split by companyCode. 
I think I'm nearly close but I miss the "near". :)
Note: I don't want to use deprecated code in Oracle 12c
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for this:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT (
          "CompanyArray",
          (  SELECT XMLAGG (
                       XMLELEMENT (
                          "CompanyElement",
                          XMLELEMENT ("companyCode", m.poclcdde),
                          XMLAGG (
                             XMLELEMENT (
                                "PolicyElement",
                                XMLFOREST (s.polinpol AS "policyNumber",
                                           s.politipo AS "productCode")))))
                       xml_payload
               FROM dtpocl m, dtpoli s
              WHERE     m.poclcdde = s.policdde
                    AND m.poclnpol = s.polinpol
                    AND m.poclcdcl = 202126
           GROUP BY m.poclcdde))
  FROM DUAL;
```

Just join the two tables and keep outside the `CompanyArray` element.
Simple (as I had thought).

Thanks!